# Continuing USSD request (Android)

Tags: android, ussd

It is well known that menu driven USSD applications are always got it's pre defined order of taking parameters in. for Example
User sends #111# (Sri Lanka), and gets a menu of about 12 sub items to select by sending its sub menu number back. Then it may ask to select another one from a set of sub menu. Send the number etc. etc. and send pin, send phone number to reload (if it is reloading) then send yes(1) no(2) to confirm then 99 to finish USSD event.
I have succeeded sending continues signals from VB.NET to phone using NOKIA ASHA 501 (using its Bluetooth outgoing com port) as follows.

```
        strCommand = "AT+CUSD=1," & Chr(34) & "#111#" & Chr(34) & ",15" & vbCrLf
        comport.Write(strCommand)
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

This will bring up the USSD menu. The DataReceivedHandler of the com port port.DataReceived can give you if there is any error returned like com is not open to error dialing USSD.
Next I will send is response string contains "OK"

```
    strCommand = "AT+CUSD=1," & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & ",15" & vbCrLf
    comport.Write(strCommand)
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Again check for OK etc. This works and I wanted to do this from Android.
Succeeded up to getting the first menu as follows.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            call(encodedHash + "111" + encodedHash);
        }
    });
}

protected void call(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + phoneNumber)), 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        view.append("\n Here \n " + "\n" + e.toString() + " hi");//
    }
}
```

So far so good.
I don't need to read the response from USSD. Just want to send next command like "1" to the same USSD thread giving a sleep time of 4/5 seconds.
If i use the same way, it brings up another thread calling the number "1"

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            call(encodedHash + "1" + encodedHash);
startActivityForResult(
                new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + phoneNumber)), 1);
```

Tried many things (without any lead from so many documents rotating).

Thanks in advance. ***All those cods above are taken from great places like stackoverflow and they are working***.

Comment: Got the answer myself. replaced line <br />
call(encodedHash + "111" + encodedHash); with this one.<br />
call(encodedHash + "121*1*1*1*99" + encodedHash);
you have to know each function of USSD as per your provider. I got this by going through each function and the one i have given here is to get the lottery result as sms to the phone (Sri Lanka)